# On which existing work is Legends of Tomorrow based?

Tags: comic-adaptation, legends-of-tomorrow, arrowverse

From the trailers of **Legends of Tomorrow**, [Rip Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Hunter) (time traveler) gathers a team of heroes and villains to fight with [Vandal Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandal_Savage). And he refers to them as legends rather than heroes. I wonder what existing DC comic it's based on. I don't know any team with this kind of roster. Or is it an original work?

*Note: Legend is Tomorrow is an upcoming continuation work of Arrow and The Flash.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a team in the comics with [that particular ensemble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_Tomorrow) (Firestorm, The Atom, White Canary, Rip Hunter, Hawkgirl, Heatwave, and Captain Cold). It looks like an original work based on characters that were already introduced in the CW's other shows, *Flash* and *Arrow*, with the exception of Rip Hunter, who is a new character to TV.  The concept looks similar to several stories involving [Rip Hunter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rip_Hunter) in the comics, where he assembles teams of heroes (or works with existing teams) from different time periods to work on one mission.

Comment: I am not going for  that particular ensemble but about the concept as a whole, story inspiration etc.

Comment: @AnkitSharma It seems like the Rip Hunter stories are what inspired the series most, from what I can tell so far.